# Groups such that all elements of even order are in $G'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

We know that $G=A_4$ is a group such that all elements of even order in $G$ are in $G':=[G,G]= V_4$, the klein four group. Are there other examples or classes of groups where all elements of even order in the group belong to the commutator subgroup?
Thanks

Comment: Is $G^{\prime}$ meant to denote the derived subgroup $[G,G]$?

Comment: If $N$ is any normal subgroup of the finite group $G$, then all elements of $G$ of even order lie in $N$ if and only if $|G/N|$ is odd.

Comment: @Derek Holt I dont think so, take $G=A_4\times Z_3$, then $G'=V_4\times 1$. In this case $G/G'\cong Z_3\times Z_3$, and hence $|G/G'|$ is odd. But we have an element $(a.b)\in G$ of order 6(take $a\in A_4$ of order 2 and $b\in Z_3$ of order 3) which is not in $G'$.

Comment: Trvially, this holds for non-commutative simple groups, like for example $\operatorname{Alt}X$ for $X$ any finite set (also for $\operatorname{card}X\le 4$).